# Escape html and whitespace?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

User input is saved in `$scope.userInput`. I want to check if the user has entered anything in the input, but I want to ignore whitespace and HTML tags, and check only for other kinds of input.

How can I do that?

Comment: `s/escape/ignore/`…? You want to *ignore* whitespace and HTML tags…?

Comment: yes, ignore, I didn't know the correct vocabulary. I will edit the question.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to allow a user to submit by just pressing space a few times?

Comment: do you want to validate it? You can simply check for blank using length property of userInput.length > 0 // has entered something. Ignore html and  whitespace String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Input string
$scope.userInput = "<h1>My input</h1>";

// Removed HTML tags from the string.
var removedTagStr = $scope.userInput.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');

// Removed the white spaces from the string.
var result = removedTagStr.replace(/ /g,'');

console.log(result); // Myinput
```

**Explanation of the regular expression `(<([^>]+)>)` :**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
<                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[^>]+                    any character except: '>' (1 or more
                         times (matching the most amount
                         possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
>                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.userInput = "<h1>My input</h1>";

var removedTagStr = $scope.userInput.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');

$scope.result = removedTagStr.replace(/ /g,'');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{result}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)|\s/ig;
var string = "Test white space and <p>HTML tags</p>";
var result = string.replace(regex, "");
console.log(result); // TestwhitespaceandHTMLtags
```